# DIV Hover makes the other DIV Move

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask your help.

http://jsfiddle.net/perRL/9/

```
<div class="header-logo">
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.bendaggers.com/wp-content/themes/Anakin%20Skywalker/Images/BenDaggers%20Logo.PNG" /></a>
</div>

<div class="xbdlogo">
<img src="http://www.bendaggers.com/wp-content/themes/Anakin%20Skywalker/Images/Bendaggers%20Logo%20Two.PNG" />
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when you hover the logo "bendaggers", the little logo beside it will change from it css style (from) **Top:-50px; to Top:30px;**

IF anyone could help me do this on javascript? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not wrong, You are achieving something like this?

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/perRL/10/)

than CSS only is enough to get the job done

CSS

```
.header-logo:hover + .xbdlogo {
    top:40px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: that was so simple! This is the first time i encounter the "+" thank you for your help!

Comment: @KareenLagasca Just a tip, use transition on class instead of class:hover so that it will move to top smoothly on mouse out - http://jsfiddle.net/perRL/12/

Comment: is it ok if i ask a related question? can i make another transition effect when the mouse pointer leaves the hovered logo? can it go back to top:-40px;?

Comment: @KareenLagasca I already answered that before you commented :)

Comment: thank you again Mr.Alien, you're very helpful. I'll accept your answer after 4 mins. the website prevents me to.